# "Request timed out." while running "PublishExtensions" step of Sitecore Commerce 9 Update 2 installation

Tags: sitecore-commerce, installation

I am trying to install Sitecore Commerce 9 Update 2 on my machine with Sitecore 9 Update 2.

I have received this exception during "PublishExtensions" step:

> Request timed out.
>
> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Request timed out.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Request timed out.
>
> Source Error:

...

I have already tried to remove previous tasks from Master_SingleServer.json as suggested [by Viet Hoang in his blog post](https://buoctrenmay.com/2018/07/15/sitecore-commerce-9-update-2-and-step-by-step-install-guide-on-your-machine/) but when trying to run it again, still receiving time out exception.

Any suggestions?

Comment: you forgot to mention, which version you are on.  By the question it seems that you are doing a fresh install

Comment: I was doing fresh installation of latest Commerce 9 Update 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this by doing publishing manually.

From Desktop, I have open Sitecore menu and selected "Publish Site":

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have then removed all tasks from Master_SingleServer.json before and also including "PublishExtensions" and run the script once again.

[image]